# How to convert an FFMPEG AVFrame in YUVJ420P to AVFoundation cVPixelBufferRef?

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, avfoundation, yuv

I have an FFMPEG `AVFrame` in `YUVJ420P` and I want to convert it to a `CVPixelBufferRef` with `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes`. The reason I want to do this is to use AVFoundation to show/encode the frames.

I selected `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange` and tried converting it since the AVFrame has the data in three planes
`Y480` `Cb240` `Cr240`. And according to what I've researched this matches the selected `kCVPixelFormatType`. By being biplanar I need to convert it into a buffer that contains `Y480` and `CbCr480` Interleaved.

I tried to create a buffer with 2 planes:

- `frame->data[0]` on the first plane,
- `frame->data[1]` and `frame->data[2]` interleaved on the second plane.

However, I'm getting return error `-6661 (invalid a)` from `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes`:

```
"Invalid function parameter. For example, out of range or the wrong type."
```

I don't have expertise on image processing at all, so any pointers to documentation that can get me started in the right approach to this problem are appreciated. My C skills aren't top of the line either so maybe I'm making a basic mistake here.

```
    uint8_t **buffer = malloc(2*sizeof(int *));
    buffer[0] = frame->data[0];
    buffer[1] = malloc(frame->linesize[0]*sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i<frame->linesize[0]; i++){
        if(i%2){
            buffer[1][i]=frame->data[1][i/2];
        }else{
            buffer[1][i]=frame->data[2][i/2];
        }
    }

    int ret = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(NULL, frame->width, frame->height, kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange, buffer, frame->linesize[0], NULL, 0, NULL, cvPixelBufferSample)
```

The frame is the `AVFrame` with the rawData from FFMPEG Decoding.

Comment: Is `cvPixelBufferSample` a CVPixelBufferRef? If so, that last parameter in `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes()` would need to be `&cvPixelBufferSample` instead to allow the pointer to the new pixel buffer to be returned by reference.

Answer (score 7):

> My C skills aren't top of the line either so maybe im making a basic mistake here.

You're making several:

- You should be using `CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes()`. I do not know if `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes()` can be used to create a planar video frame; if so, it will require a pointer to a "plane descriptor block" (I can't seem to find the struct in the docs).
- `frame->linesize[0]` is the *bytes per row*, not the size of the whole image. The docs are unclear, but the [usage](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/y41pdec_8c_source.html#l00044) is fairly unambiguous.
- `frame->linesize[0]` refers to the Y plane; you care about the UV planes.
- Where is `sizeof(int)` from?
- You're passing in `cvPixelBufferSample`; you might mean `&cvPixelBufferSample`.
- You're not passing in a release callback. The documentation does not say that you can pass `NULL`.

Try something like this:

```
size_t srcPlaneSize = frame->linesize[1]*frame->height;
size_t dstPlaneSize = srcPlaneSize *2;
uint8_t *dstPlane = malloc(dstPlaneSize);
void *planeBaseAddress[2] = { frame->data[0], dstPlane };

// This loop is very naive and assumes that the line sizes are the same.
// It also copies padding bytes.
assert(frame->linesize[1] == frame->linesize[2]);
for(size_t i = 0; i<srcPlaneSize; i++){
    // These might be the wrong way round.
    dstPlane[2*i  ]=frame->data[2][i];
    dstPlane[2*i+1]=frame->data[1][i];
}

// This assumes the width and height are even (it's 420 after all).
assert(!frame->width%2 && !frame->height%2);
size_t planeWidth[2] = {frame->width, frame->width/2};
size_t planeHeight[2] = {frame->height, frame->height/2};
// I'm not sure where you'd get this.
size_t planeBytesPerRow[2] = {frame->linesize[0], frame->linesize[1]*2};
int ret = CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes(
        NULL,
        frame->width,
        frame->height,
        kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange,
        NULL,
        0,
        2,
        planeBaseAddress,
        planeWidth,
        planeHeight,
        planeBytesPerRow,
        YOUR_RELEASE_CALLBACK,
        YOUR_RELEASE_CALLBACK_CONTEXT,
        NULL,
        &cvPixelBufferSample);
```

Memory management is left as an exercise to the reader, but for test code you might get away with passing in `NULL` instead of a release callback.